# Is there a word for tangible progressive action towards a conscious goal?

Tags: single-word-requests

Progressive action as opposed to speculative or hopeful action (daydreaming, prayer, etc.) Doing something in the present to actively contribute to your goal.

Comment: There’s always *progress.*

Answer (score 1):

That can be called a ***step***

Defined by [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/step_1#step_1__13) as:

> one of a series of actions that you do in order to achieve a particular aim.

> *This agreement is an important step towards our goal.*

Comment: +1 Yes, and "we can do it step-by-step"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the term ***[advancement:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advancement)***

> - progression to a higher stage of development

(M-W)

Answer (score 0):

There is our *Effort*. This is a reflection of the steps (from Jim and Macmillan) we have taken towards our goal.